# Is $e-1/e$ rational?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

My intuition tells me that it's not rational, and even not algebraic (i.e., it's transcendental).

But I'm having a hard time showing it.

Taking it slightly further, $e-\frac1e=\frac{e^2-1}{e}=\frac{(e+1)(e-1)}{e}$, but I don't feel I'm in the right direction.

Any ideas how to tackle this one?

Thank you!

Comment: $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: if $e-\frac1e=\alpha$ were algebraic than $e=\dfrac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4}}2$ would be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p$ and $q$ are integers and

$$\frac{e^2-1}{e} = \frac{p}{q}$$

Then $qe^2-pe-q = 0$, so $e$ would satisfy a quadratic polynomial over the integers.  Since $e$ is not algebraic, that gives a contradiction.

Comment: Comment above (by Angina Seng) says "$e$ is transcendental". Can you please confirm?

Comment: $e$ is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), i.e., not algebraic

Comment: Sorry, I thought that algebraic and transcendental are two disjoint groups (no elements in common). So how can $e$ be both algebraic and transcendental?

Comment: I think $e$ *would be*  algebraic was intended, and that gives a contradiction

Comment: Above it was already proven that the number must be transcendental. This is only an irrationality proof.

Comment: Yup, I agree on that; Was only interested in the irrationality of the expression. Thank y'all!

Comment: Just a typo. I put in a "not".